# Ggplot2 warning "Removed X rows containing missing values (geom_segment)" while values don't seem to be missing

Tags: ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to display a lot (3913) of segments in a ggplot2 plot (using a ggmap cartographic visualisation).

Here's my data set, where each row is a segment:

```
       lat1    long1      lat2    long2          w
1 -119.4093 49.00574 -119.4221 49.00955  4.3029279
2 -119.4093 49.00574 -119.4233 49.01523  0.3375000
3 -119.4896 49.00544 -119.5176 49.00582  0.1285714
4 -119.4896 49.00544 -119.5063 49.01168  1.2277778
5 -119.5176 49.00582 -119.5630 49.00582  0.0900000
6 -119.5176 49.00582 -119.5160 49.00898 45.2909774

Full dataset here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/csvLinesWetlands.csv
```

Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

# Get the map from Google and put it in ggmap:
al1 = get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -119.539277502884, lat = 49.1698636938748), zoom = 10, scale = 2, maptype = 'terrain')
map = ggmap(al1, extent = 'device')

# Put CSV file in edges:
edges <- read.csv("/csvLinesWetlands.csv", header=TRUE)

# Draw all the segment in "map":
map <- map + geom_segment(data=edges, aes(x= long1, y=lat1, xend=long2, yend=lat2))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following warning message when running this code:

> Removed 3913 rows containing missing values (geom_segment)

And no segment is actually displayed on the map (3913 is the total number of rows/segments in my dataset).

There are no missing data that I am aware of... What am I doing wrong here?

PS. There are a few questions on Stackoverflow that address this problem, but none have helped me figuring this out.

Comment: It looks like a lat and lon got reversed somewhere.  Compare lat and long in the edges dataframe with lat and lon for the map center.

Comment: That was it... I can't believe this was just this. Thanks so much... Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?